# How to change the architecture of my simple sequential model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, training, keras

I'm new to Deep Learning with `Keras`. With some tutorials online for cat vs non-cat classification, I was able to compile this simple architecture for my own classification problem. However, my target application is **fire detection** which essentially might have semantic differences with cats.

After training, I realized this model is accurate when the fire scene is simple and visible, but if many objects inside or fire is a bit smaller, it fails to detect. So I thought maybe I can change the architecture by increasing the complexity.

First thing came into my mind was increasing the first layer filters from `32` to `64` by changing to `model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1)))`

Is it going to help? What are other best practices to change the architecture? How about increasing the number of kernels to `kernel_size = (5, 5)` or adding one more layer or even changing the images from grayscale to colored?

Here is my original training code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from PIL import Image
from random import shuffle, choice
import numpy as np
import os

IMAGE_SIZE = 256
IMAGE_DIRECTORY = './data/test_set'

def label_img(name):
  if name == 'cats': return np.array([1, 0])
  elif name == 'notcats' : return np.array([0, 1])

def load_data():
  print("Loading images...")
  train_data = []
  directories = next(os.walk(IMAGE_DIRECTORY))[1]

  for dirname in directories:
    print("Loading {0}".format(dirname))
    file_names = next(os.walk(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, dirname)))[2]

    for i in range(200):
      image_name = choice(file_names)
      image_path = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, dirname, image_name)
      label = label_img(dirname)
      if "DS_Store" not in image_path:
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        img = img.convert('L')
        img = img.resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        train_data.append([np.array(img), label])

  return train_data

def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', 
                   input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1)))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

  return model

training_data = load_data()
training_images = np.array([i[0] for i in training_data]).reshape(-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1)
training_labels = np.array([i[1] for i in training_data])

print('creating model')
model = create_model()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print('training model')
model.fit(training_images, training_labels, batch_size=50, epochs=10, verbose=1)
model.save("model.h5")
```